# Не работают POST-запросы в C#

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, post

В web-приложении работает Get-запрос, однако не работает Post-запрос.

```
using Jint;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.Map("/Home", async (context) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("You are in HOME page");
});

app.MapGet("/Product", async (context) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("You are in PRODUCT page");
});

app.MapPost("/Product", async (context) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("A new PRODUCT created");
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

[image: Network в хроме:]

Comment: в заголовке про POST звпрос, на скрине успешный GET запрос.

Comment: А где показано, что не работает?

Comment: @tym32167 В том то и дело. Сейчас к эндпоинту /Product привязаны два запроса - GET и POST, но вызывается только GET.

Comment: @aepot на скриншоте в вызываемых методах только GET-запрос. POST-а почему-то не наблюдается.

Comment: Не совсем ясна проблема. Вы показываете код сервера и скрин где кто то выполняет гет запрос. Вызвать пост запрос может только клиент, раз пост запрос не вызывается - ищите проблему на клиенте.

Comment: @tym32167 Я запускаю это приложение и тестирую по локалке (localhost:7251/Product). Открываю веб-страницу, открываю в Хроме инструменты разработчика - из двух запросов /Product срабатывает только GET. В этом и заключается проблема, POST ведь тоже должен вызываться.

Comment: Чем вызываться? Покажите вызываюший код.

Comment: Если вы делаете запросы просто из браузера, то `post` запрос делается через `html` страничку с элементом `form`, например. Через просто обращение на страницу по `url` делается только `get` запрос.

Comment: @aepot Вызывающий код: app.MapPost("/Product", async (context) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("A new PRODUCT created");
});

Comment: @CrazyElf
Хорошо, в таком случае подскажите пожалуйста, эту страничку необходимо создать с помощью инструмента Razor Pages? Или каким-то другим способом?

Comment: `app.MapPost` - это _вызываемый_, а не _вызывающий_ код.

Comment: В Visual Studio относительно недавно появилась фича [.http files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/http-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0). С её помощью можете тестировать свой API. Или можно для этой цели взять внешнее приложение. Самым известным является Postman (но это такой тяжеловесный монстр...)

Comment: @tridjam Да просто обычную `<form>`  с `submit` в `html`-е сделайте.

Comment: Выше дело говорят. Когда вы открываете ссылку в браузере, браузер посылает гет запрос на сервер. Чтобы отправить пост запрос надо либо через html формы, либо каким то спец инструментом типа postman.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем, кто уделил внимание данному вопросу, в особенности        @CrazyElf , ваша рекомендация с созданием html страницы и отправкой POST-запроса с ее использованием оказалось очень ценной и помогла решить проблему.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]